# Storing spring configuration in a class versus xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Currently my spring configurations are in a xml file (the traditionaly way).

One thing that i like about this is during deployment I can deploy a different version that has my production settings, or say in a test environment I can have test settings there.

I like the idea of having things configured in a class, but that will get compiled into my war and then it won't be as flexible.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4):

Java configuration is great and it has several advantages:

- refactoring-friendly
- type-safety
- much more flexible (you can write any Java code, not being bound to XML semantics and capabilities).

> I can deploy a different version that has my production settings, or say in a test environment I can have test settings there.

Investigate [Spring `@Profile`s](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/). They are orthogonal to your question (work both in XML and `@Configuration`) but are best suited in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the only two ways available. If you don't want configuration baked in code, then you have to go with xml.

Answer (score 0):

The spring reference manual includes a section on combining both Java and XML configuration.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-combining

If you tend to be more XML centric you can bootstrap your app using XML and then introduce Java config as needed in an ad-hoc fashion.  This might be a good way to ease into it.  You might decide to go Java config all the way.